# Displaying morning, afternoon, or evening to user based on time using variables

Tags: javascript, html, time

I want to say "Good morning, User" (morning can be changed to afternoon or evening) my code is not working. I'd appreciate any assistance.

**index.html snippet**

```
 <h1 class="mx-3 text-center display-3">Good <span id="time"></span>, Username</h1>
```

**master.js**

```
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()
var time = null;

if (curHr < 12) {
  var time = "Morning";
} else if (curHr < 18) {
  var time = "Afternoon";
} else {
  var time = "Evening";
}

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;
```

Sorry, I'm a noob at javascript.

I'd also like to know what this error means (from google chrome console):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at master.js:13
```

Comment: Please post your entire code for this including the part where you link the JS file.

Comment: Note: You don't need to put `var` in front of every use of a variable. You need declare a variable only once, at the beginning.

Comment: Each of those var declarations should end in a semi-colon as well.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are linking the javascript file before the span, then
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at master.js:13` will occur since it can't find the span yet. Try:

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;
}
```

Comment: @SmocksMCM great, if it solved it hit the checkmark to the left of the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow :).

Comment: @SmocksMCM: The better approach than the above is just to ensure that your `script` tag is at the *end* of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag. The window `load` event happens **very** late in the page load process, after all images and other ancillary resources are loaded. It's hardly ever the right answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree that JS should be at the end, although I feel that you should never rely on code that runs as the page is being constructed. In my opinion best practice is always to do your code in an `onload`. Looks cleaner to have your link with the other links anyways, and it all downloads at the same time so you don't get choppy page loading. Not trying to be rude, I realize you are a higher level than me.

Comment: @pepperjack: (Rep is irrelevant) You can certainly have your own opinion, but putting scripts at the bottom is ***very*** well-established (and has been for years), does speed apparent page load time (you can mitigate that with `async`/`defer`, but with concomittant complexity), and is not problematic or in any way unreliable. More: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom In contrast, using `load` runs your scripts far too late, leaving plenty of time for the user to do things before they run.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for linking that, looks interesting. I'll give it a read later.